# RTL images are not flipped inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage, right-to-left

I have an app where I need to support Right-To-Left language. The system takes care of everything almost automatically. Except for images.

Some of them (arrows) need to be flipped. In the Assets catalog I set the 'Direction' property of those images  to 'Left To Right, Mirrors'.

This works well with images that are used for buttons (both simple buttons and navigation bar buttons), but the problem occurs when it comes to images that are used in image views inside the table view cell.

When the table is displayed, they are not flipped. When I tap a cell, selecting it, the image flips and remains flipped afterwards. So, I need to tap each cell to flip their images.

I have tried to use `imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()`, but to no effect. Same with `withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()`.

Do you have ideas of how to fix that?

P.S. Adding screenshot on request. Top 3 cells have already been tapped, so arrows are flipped as expected. Bottom cells display unflipped images.

[image: Screenshot]

Top 3 cells have already been tapped, so arrows are flipped as expected. Bottom cells display unflipped images.

Comment: Upload output screenshot for easy to understand

Comment: Done. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this is the fix I've found so far.

As long as iOS cannot mirror the image correctly for some reason, I've set 'Direction' property to 'Both' and added the right-to-left set of images.

That solved the problem.

[image]

Comment: can we do LTR to RTL at run time without restarting app?

Comment: You can call `UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft` to force RTL dynamically, but that works only for UIView and its descendants. Navigation bars and images do not perform any changes. This is because they rely on `UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection` and you cannot modify it in code. At least, I didn't find any dynamic way to do that.

Comment: unfortunately sometimes it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a bug with `UIImageView` since - as you stated - it works for an image in a `UIButton`. The trick is to set the image programmatically (instead of selecting it in interface builder). Then the RTL system works as expected:

```
yourImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")
```

Comment: This is an easier fix than the one mentioned by @Evgeniy above. Important to note that if you were previously setting an image in Interface Builder, you must remove that (i.e blank out the image property in Interface Builder) for this workaround to work correctly.